# Javascript how can I get a particular child from an object/element returned by elementFromPoint()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent-child

Is there a way to retrieve the child element from an element/object returned by the function elementFromPoint(x, y);

Suppose I have the following statement,

```
var elem = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
```

And lets assume that the element returned and stored in variable elem would have the following structure:

```
<section class="wrapper">
      some unwraped text
      <div class="hidden">
           <img />
      </div>
</section>
```

Is there away to retrieve the the img tag from this section wrapper? I am looking to retrieve it and clone it using jQuery and further add the clone to another element. The div wrapping the image tag has a css property of display: none; which will hide the image, I would like to sort of copy that image and reveal it inside some other element.

However I need to find a way to retrieve the img tag before I can clone it and append it further.

EDITED

So this is how I am trying to use the elem object, I need the child img out of it rather than the whole returned element

```
  $('#unique > img').remove();
  $('#unique').append($(elem > child)
        .clone()
        .children()
        .end());
```

I believe I don't need the children() function if I can get the right element right up.

Thank ...

Comment: `$(elem).find('img')` ?

Comment: Or `$("img", elem)`, to specify the `context` argument of the selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does `elem` end up being? The `<section>`?

```
$(elem).find('.hidden img')
```

One of its children?

```
$(elem).closest('.wrapper').find('.hidden img')
```

Comment: so the element returned by elementFromPoint(x, y) is the whole HTML section mentioned in my question, in other words after the function call the elem will hold all those tags. I would like to extract the img tag out of the elem element

Comment: @twimB: So use `$(elem).find('.hidden img')`?

Answer (score 1):

Check if this works:

```
$("img",$(document.elementFromPoint(x, y)))
```

or

```
$(document.elementFromPoint(x, y)).find("img")
```

Comment: Thanks alot, it works with the second, ill give it a go with your first variant also.

Answer (score 1):

```
var elem = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
var imageElement = $(elem).find("div.hidden img")
```